# Sending an email to ALL email addresses of EVERY member in a group with new CONTACTS

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts-group

I used to be able to add multiple email addresses for a single contact to a group label. Now - you can just add the label to the contact and it selects just one email address to use.  How do I get back the 'old functionality'?

Answer (score 0):

The "old functionality" was discontinued, with the introduction of the new label system. The only workaround is to split email addresses and have it each per contact and then label/group them individually.